# Owner can't push to organization repository

Tags: github, permissions, push, organization

today I've moved my private github repository to newly created organization (of which I'm an owner). I've changed my remote origin to git@github.com:organization/repo.git. I'm not able to push to remote because I've got an error saying

> Error: Permission to organization/repo.git denied to MyGithubUsername.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I've checked that my account is owner of organization and repository exists.

Comment: Are you sure that the organization and repo were successfully created? GitHub has had major service issues over the last ~20 hours.

Comment: Everything looks ok. https://github.com/MealkyTeam/Mealky

Comment: Are you sure that the moved repo is still aware of your ssh key?

Comment: My key id_rsa.pub was already added to my github account. I've added it again  but problem persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer. Maybe I did something wrong, or maybe it was because of github issues, but even if I was stated as an owner of Organization I had only rights to read repository. I couldn't change permission for myself because "you can't change permission for owner". I changed permissions for all members to admin, and because for now I'm the only one member of organization it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 10):

Disable third-party application access restrictions as suggested in [atom/github #1010.422882361](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/1010#issuecomment-422882361).

Comment: This is crazy, but it fixes it for me. I double checked my ssh keys, even made new ones, nothing worked. I am the organisation owner, other members had no issues. I had no issues with my personal repos. Seems like a bug in github. The fix was as shown here, go to organisation settings, scroll down to 3rd party access, choose oauth application policy, then disable restrictions...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem today and indeed as Ephellon Dantzler suggests, disabling 3rd-party access restrictions fixed it.

However, I did not really like that solution so I started reading the documentation. On the [About OAuth App access reistrictions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-oauth-app-access-restrictions) page, Github mentions that enabling 3rd party restrictions will block:

> SSH keys created before February 2014 immediately lose access to the organization's resources (this includes user and deploy keys).

I created my key well before that so I just created a new SSH key and added to Github following [their instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

After that, I was able to interface with my organization's private repository even when 3rd-party access restrictions was enabled.

Comment: there's no need to disable 3rd-Party access restrictions. Apparently the problem is with the ssh encryption, so generating a new key pair (hopefully with ed25519) an uploading it to github solves the problem.

Comment: @GabrielCabrera Right -- as my post states, this is probably a case of your key being too old.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I'm still getting the error repository not found. Although, using a Personal Access token did work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found to this problem was creating a P.A.T (Personal Access Token) and using it in the spot of my password when pushing to the repo.

The way you can create a P.A.T is by going to:

Github.com >Login> Settings> Developer Settings> Personal Access Tokens > Generate New Token. I selected all the options for my token and then copied the token that was generated and used it as my password when I was asked to enter my credentials.

This took me a few hours to figure out and was very frustrating. I hope this info can help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I could not push commits from GoLand/IntelliJ to my GitHub organization repo.

The solution that worked for me is

1. Go to `https://github.com/organizations/<orgname>/settings/oauth_application_policy`
2. Set policy `Policy: No restrictions`

Answer (score 0):

Using GitHub Desktop..I was having a weird bug where I was owner of the organization, and admin of the repo(I had full rights) on my organization's repo. I decided to go into the command line, and push from there (Type "git push") and that fixed it!
It pushed, and I could now push from GitHub Desktop again.
Weird, but hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For me, everything was ok in the Settings and with my key. Yet Github Desktop could not push (or even fetch) to/from the remote because it didn't trust the IP address. To find and fix I switched to the CLI and ran:

```
git fetch
```

which replied with

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<long string>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

therefore revealing the issue. Either Github has changed their IP or I hadn't connected to this repo on my new machine (with the old key). Replying `yes` added the IP to my `.ssh/known_hosts` and then Github Desktop worked just fine again.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.114.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this issue recently with an SSH key generated in 2018 and [Ephellon Grey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59795212/1071320) pointed me in the right direction. My personal SSH key was added to GitHub by SourceTree and SourceTree was not an authorized third-party app on my organization page. Hence pushes authorized with that SSH key were being rejected. I just had to grant third-party access to SourceTree on the organization and now I can push to repos contained within.

Comment: How did you grant third-party access to SourceTree on the organization? In my case, I can see "SourcetreeForMac" is an authorized OAuth app in my personal account but I can't see any means of adding it to my organization account.