# Can't push to organization repository and I'm the owner

Tags: git

I just converted one of my GitHub pages to an organization and made my personal GitHub username the owner of this organization. However, I still can't write changes to the GitHub repository. I noticed that the suggested solution here [Owner can't push to organization repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936638/owner-cant-push-to-organization-repository) mentioned that he changed permissions for **all** users from Read to Admin.

I don't want to do this, so I'm not quite sure if there's an actual workaround. It seems that the owner should always have read/write permissions.

Here's my `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:my-org-repo/leprechaun.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

And here's the error that I'm getting when trying to push to it:

```
[root:kali:~/scripts/leprechaun]# git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to [obfuscated]/leprechaun.git denied to MyGitHubUsername.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've ensured that I can clone with no problems using the SSH URL, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

*Command Output Examples*

```
[root:kali:~/scripts/leprechaun]# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi [myuername]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Often this is an ssh issue. [What does `ssh -T git@github.com` say?](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection)

Comment: Updated the original post to reflect results.

Comment: Are you using your actual username or the string "MyGitHubUsername"?

Comment: Have you make sure the Collaborators of the repo includes and have the correct permission

Comment: @DrCord I'm using my actual username. That's just redacted in the example above.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne I can see the collaborators but not where to manage their permissions other than managing "Members" permission to the Organization page.

Comment: If you have a more than one user need to be added to the repo, you might want to create a team first and add the team to the Collaborators section. Then set permission as a team, Or just type your user name on the **Search by username, full name or email address** search box and add to the repo. https://imgur.com/tfzWlIr

Comment: https://imgur.com/mwhPbQ7

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Please Make sure that this solution is only tested in Linux.

**I am not sure what happened for me but here is how i fixed it!**

**1st step:**

 using terminal navigate to the project folder you are trying to use push with

**2nd step:**

run:

> ssh -T git@github.com
> Blockquote

you should get a response like this:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> Blockquote

**3rd step:**

 using ssh-add add your owner ssh key to ssh agent

> ssh-add ~/.ssh/SOMEFOLDER/SOMESSHKEY.

Unlock key with your passphrase and the identity will be added, what remains then is to verify that you can connect using ssh, so try again with **2nd step**

if you receive a message like this:

> Hi {YOUR OWNER USERNAME HERE} ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Congratulations!! you can push commits now without much of a problem.